# Question about convergence in weak operator topology (from Reed and Simon)

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory

I am reading over Chapter VI in Simon and Reed's Functional Analysis. In the first section, the discussion covers various topologies defined on $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$, the space of bounded linear operators between Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$.

In particular, the authors define the weak operator topology via convergence of nets:

A net of operators $\{T_\alpha\}$ converges to an operator $T \iff$ for all $x \in X$ and $l \in \mathcal{L}(Y, \mathbb{C})$, we have $|l(T_{\alpha}(x)) - l(T(x))| \to  0$.

Then the following example is given (page 184 of the text):

The operators $W_n$ on the (Hilbert space) $l_2$ are given  by $W_n(x_1, x_2, \dots) = (0, \dots 0, x_1, x_2, \dots)$ (zeros appearing in the first $n$ places). Then $W_n \to 0$ in the weak operator topology on $\mathcal{L}(l_2, l_2)$.

I have not been able to work out why this convergence is true. I know that, to establish the convergence, I need to take arbitrary $l \in Y^*$ and $ x = (x_1, x_2, \dots) \in l_2$ and show that $|l(0, \dots, 0, x_1, x_2)| \to 0$ (zeros in the first $n$ places again). But for the life of me I can't figure out why this would be true for arbitrary $l$ and $x$.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Each element $l\in Y^\star$ is represented by a special $(y_i)_i\in l_2$ and so $l(z)=\sum_i y_i z_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete @Vobo's hint : For $l \in Y^{\ast}$, choose $y=(y_n) \in Y$ (by the Riesz Representation theorem) such that
$$
l(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_ny_n
$$
In particular, note that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_ny_n$ is a convergent series. Now,
$$
|l(W_n(x))| = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} x_{k-n+1}y_k
$$
is the tail of that convergent series, and hence $|l(W_n(x))| \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I just have one thing to clear up. Shouldn't we have $l(0, \dots , x_1, x_2, \dots) = \sum_{k=n}^\infty y_kx_{k-n +1}$? But I think this will still go to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, since $\{x_n\}$ (being in $l_2$) is bounded.

Comment: @jtms88 : You are right of course. Thanks. edited.